# I need to index firebase data to algolia , rules in firebase for both read and write requires Authentication (auth!=null)

Tags: node.js, firebase, algolia

I am using the code described in the algolia docs. It is working when firebase rules allow both read and write without authentication. This does not work with data which requires authentication. What I can do to add auth in below code ?
I tried using firebase-admin, I think this method will work only when rule is changed to allow read for a single uid.

```
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const firebase = require('firebase');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./config/serviceAccountKey.json");

// load values from the .env file in this directory into process.env
dotenv.config();


admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
});

firebase.initializeApp({
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
});

admin
  .auth()
  .createCustomToken('siddharth')
  .then((customToken) => {
    console.log(customToken);
    firebase.auth().authenticateWithCustomToken(customToken);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
  });

// admin.auth.createCustomToken('siddharth').then(token => {

// });


const database = firebase.database();
const algolia = algoliasearch(
    process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
    process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY
);
const index = algolia.initIndex(process.env.ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);

database.ref('/questions').once('value', questions => {
    const records = [];
    questions.forEach(question => {
        // get the key and data from the snapshot
        const childKey = question.key;
        const childData = question.val();
        // We set the Algolia objectID as the Firebase .key
        childData.objectID = childKey;
        // Add object for indexing
        records.push(childData);
    });

    console.log(records);
    // Add or update new objects
    index
        .saveObjects(records)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('questions imported into Algolia');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error when importing question into Algolia', error);
            process.exit(1);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this seems to be a Node.js script that accesses Firebase Authentication by using service credentials with the Admin SDK, you can also use that Admin SDK to access the database. Accessing a Firebase service through the Admin SDK with service credentials gives full administrative access, and bypasses any security rules you may have configured for your database.

In code, change:

```
const database = firebase.database();
```

To:

```
const database = admin.database();
```